# Передача вектора в качестве аргумента функции

Tags: c++, функции, vector

Здравствуйте, я только недавно начал изучать C++, поэтому проблема может показаться дурацкой, но надеюсь, что поможете.
 Проблема такая, решил для практики написать простую программку, которая запрашивает количество заказанных блюд, их названия и цену, а потом выводит на экран уже с общей суммой.
 Для цен и наименований блюд сделал два вектора, а вывод и подсчёт суммы выделил в отдельную функцию, но компилятор ругается на вызов этой функции и выдаёт ошибку "no matching function for call to "total"". Я пробовал сделать то же уже с обычным массивом и всё заработало, но всё же хочется узнать, что не так я делал с векторами.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void line(){
    for (int i=0; i<46; i++) {
        cout<<"*";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}

int total(int kol_vo, string dish[], int cost[]){
    int sum=0;
    line();
    for (int i=0; i<kol_vo; i++) {
        sum+=cost[i];
        cout<<dish[i]<<" : "<<cost[i]<<endl;
    }
    line();
    return sum;
}
int main(){
    cout<<"Введите количество позиций: ";
    int kol;
    cin>>kol;
    vector<string>dishes(kol);
    vector<string>cost(kol);
    for (int i=0; i<kol; i++) {
        cout<<"Введите название блюда "<<i+1<<": ";
        cin>>dishes[i];
        cout<<"Введите цену блюда "<<i+1<<": ";
        cin>>cost[i];
    }
    cout<<"Общий счёт: "<<total(kol,dishes, cost);//Вот тут показывает ошибку

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: так у тебя ж в определении функции у параметров не вектора

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Лучше так:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void line(){
    for (int i=0; i<46; i++) {
        cout<<"*";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}

int total(const vector<string>&dish, const vector<int>&cost)
{
    int kol_vo = dish.size();
    int sum=0;
    line();
    for (int i=0; i<kol_vo; i++) {
        sum+=cost[i];
        cout<<dish[i]<<" : "<<cost[i]<<endl;
    }
    line();
    return sum;
}
int main()
{
    cout<<"Введите количество позиций: ";
    int kol;
    cin>>kol;
    vector<string>dishes(kol);
    vector<int>   cost(kol);
    for (int i=0; i<kol; i++) {
        cout<<"Введите название блюда "<<i+1<<": ";
        cin>>dishes[i];
        cout<<"Введите цену блюда "<<i+1<<": ";
        cin>>cost[i];
    }
    cout<<"Общий счёт: "<<total(dishes, cost);//Вот тут показывает ошибку

    return 0;
}
```

Вектор сам помнит количество записей в нем; кроме того, `sum+=cost[i];` для строк просто не сработает - строки же надо переводить в числа, перед тем как суммировать.

Но я бы собрал в один вектор и название, и цену - так меньше шансов какого-то рассогласования. Здесь я использовал стандартный шаблон `pair<>`, но можно написать и свою структуру:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
using namespace std;

void line()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 46; i++)
    {
        cout << "*";
    }

    cout << endl;
}

int total(const vector<pair<string, int>>& dish)
{
    int kol_vo = dish.size();
    int sum = 0;
    line();

    for (int i = 0; i < kol_vo; i++)
    {
        sum += dish[i].second;
        cout << dish[i].first << " : " << dish[i].second << endl;
    }

    line();
    return sum;
}
int main()
{
    cout << "Введите количество позиций: ";
    int kol;
    cin >> kol;
    vector<pair<string, int>> dishes(kol);

    for (int i = 0; i < kol; i++)
    {
        cout << "Введите название блюда " << i + 1 << ": ";
        cin >> dishes[i].first;
        cout << "Введите цену блюда " << i + 1 << ": ";
        cin >> dishes[i].second;
    }

    cout << "Общий счёт: " << total(dishes); //Вот тут показывает ошибку
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: а почему по ссылке?

Comment: @Grundy Не понял... А почему нет?

Comment: Ну а почему да?:) В данном случае разница разве будет какая-то?

Comment: @Grundy Вообще-то копировать все строки - а вдруг их будет много - как-то нехорошо...

Comment: Разобрался. Спасибо за помощь.